# Gmail Older/Newer arrow buttons do nothing

Tags: email, gmail

When I'm in my Gmail inbox, I click the "Older"/"Newer" arrows in the upper-right of Gmail, in order to look at emails further back than 50, but nothing happens. It just says "loading" at the top for a few seconds, and it says "51-100 of 21749" but it still shows me the first page of emails.

I've tried this on Opera, Chrome, and IE, in incognito mode, at home, and at work, and it works the same in each case.

I've included a screenshot to demonstrate this. I've censored the email subjects, but you can still see that the emails are the same by the dates on the right, which remain the same whether I'm looking at emails 1-50, or 51-100.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ZIpXOXW.png]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug posted as a question. It should be reported  to Google using Send Feedback

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It looks like this is a bug in Gmail.

Mousing over the Inbox on the left, there is a dropdown menu.  It was set to "Default". I switched the Inbox from "Default", to "Important", then "Unread", then "Priority", and finally back to "Default".  This caused the Older/Newer buttons to start working again on all platforms.

[image: ViewingGmailInboxTypeDropDownMenu]